# Quich launch with siblings and items below siblings

Tags: 2013, navigation, quick-launch

How can I configure (change or develop) quick launch in SharePoint 2013 so that it displays the current site and items below current site, and current site's siblings AND items below currents site's siblings. 
Also siblings and items below siblings.
The default option shows current site and items below it and siblings. it does not display item below siblings.

Thank you and appreciate all kind of advice.